# Computer will not boot. Black screen with cursor only

Tags: boot

I tried to install ubuntu to my toshiba satellite from a created disc.  After setting partitions, install took extreme amount of time and then shut down.  I now can not boot any operating system.  A black screen with a cursor in the left upper corner is the only thing that comes up.  I can reach the bios screen only by hitting f2 at start up.
I have tried a restore with original restore discs but nothing is recognized.  I have tried to boot ubuntu from disc but nothing is recognized.  So nothing boots from cd drive.  What else can I do?  Is there a way to wipe clean the computer and simply install ubuntu on fresh?  No other f key works on start up except for f2 into bios screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a hard-disk problem, are you sure, that you're hard disk is OK?
(for a quick check you can unplug it, and try then to boot from CD/USB drive. Ok, for a laptop this won't be so quick, but maybe you can check from bios) Ubuntu should boot from USB or CD even if you don't have a hard drive, and for me it take long time to boot, when I had a faulty hard drive...

Comment: I know that the hard-disk was okay before my attempt to install ubuntu.  I do not think I did the partition part of the install correctly but did not realize it would completely fubar the computer.  Nothing from cd will boot.  That includes the ubuntu disc that I created nor the original recovery discs for windows.  All that I can draw up is the setup utility.  I'm at a loss here.

Comment: You should check your memory first (there is an option in ubuntu from the start cd, "check memory for deffects") If you will not see an error after an hour, than it is probably ok, and you should check your hard drive. For hard disk more than 2-3 years old, it is common to become useless at a moment, at least for me happened a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Bad ram memory or bad HDD,your laptop is pretty old,Just a pice of advance,better to have a professional engineer to check it in face