# Ok Ubuntu HDD boots to black screen

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, uefi, bios

This question is similar to [this other one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469431/computer-will-not-boot-black-screen-with-cursor-only) in that I get the same result, however I am booting an apparently fine HDD.

For four days I have been booting Ubuntu 14.x on a very inexpensive laptop. I did a format and clean install on a WD Passport (will not buy again) external HDD. It works beautifully. I've just gotten home from traveling and I'm attempting to boot off the external drive on my desktop Win 8 machine. This is where the issues start.

In my boot options I **can** see the drive and select it to boot from. However, in my bios settings I **cannot** set it as a default boot option. I see only the other drives on the system. I have `Both UEFI and Legacy` set in my options. So, I cannot for the life of me figure what is wrong there.

If I manually select the external as my boot drive I get only a black screen with a white cursor as mentioned above. If I reboot from the thumb drive that is my installer I can successfully use the 'Try without installing' option'; that works fine. I am certain that it is not an integrity issue with the external dirve because I can see the files (in trial Ubuntu) and I can *still* boot the laptop off either.

**TL;DR**

Ubuntu external drive boots fine on laptop but not desktop.

Bios will allow manual boot of drive but it is not visible in default boot settings.
`UEFI and Legacy` option is set.

External drive boots to black screen with white cursor. Nothing else.

Desktop will boot pen drive with "Trial Ubuntu" and installer just fine.

Laptop will still boot either.

I am using AMD and ATI hardware but the system will run trial Ubuntu fine and I cannot seem to get into grub anyway.

How can I get my external drive to boot successfully on my desktop?

**EDIT**

After talking to Xen2050 in the comments below I think that grub is either crashing or not running. This is my best guess due to the fact that after editing /etc/default/grub to always boot with `nomodeset` (on my laptop) I still can't boot past the black screen or access grub on the desktop. [This](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a6020a279cfcc1ad8891) is my current grub.cfg with a delay added (see comments) just in case that helps.

Could this still be a driver issue?

**EDIT 2**

I'm now attempting to boot with `nomodeset`, `radeon.modeset=0', and`grub_gfxmode=1024x768x24`set in the defaults. I also attempted [this](https://mwop.net/blog/2014-11-03-utopic-and-amd.html) from the working laptop. Still cannot boot or get into grub or tty.

Comment: I'm not sure if GRUB loads on the external drive, or it crashes, or if Ubuntu crashes. Is there a GRUB menu the external drive will stop/pause at before booting Ubuntu? And any kernel/boot options on by default, that may not be working on the Desktop? Maybe need one, like `nomodeset`?

Comment: @Xen2050 I keep seeing `nomodeset` but I don't underhand how to view to try it if I can't find grub. If I hold shift after selecting my external drive in the bios I still get the Bossk screen. Additionally trial Ubuntu boots fine.

Comment: I know the trial / live / ISO ubuntu's will pause for a while, and if you press any key there are menu's where you can select "troubleshooting" options like that. If the live/trial boots good, then maybe there's a specific video or hardware driver for the laptop that doesn't work with the desktop? And if you can get to the GRUB config file on the hard drive (usually `/grub/grub.cfg`) you could look for or add a `set timeout=60` line? That might make it wait for a minute before automatically booting? May be other options there, I'm not sure

Comment: @Xen2050 Using `set timeout=60` isn't working. At least not where I'm entering it. I'm attempting to get it to boot with `nomodeset` on the laptop.

Comment: hmm... apparently from the GRUB manual (from `info grub`) setting the `timeout=-1` should make it "wait indefinitely". But maybe GRUB itself is in a funny graphics mode too, I'm not sure what that line might be in the `grub.cfg` file, maybe `gfxmode`-something... I'm not a GRUB expert, but maybe pasting the `grub.cfg` file could help/

Comment: @Xen2050 Maybe `set timeout=60` works after all. I am able to boot with `nomodeset` on the laptop and it appears to also respect the sixty seconds in `grub.cfg`. Therefore I'm assuming that grub is crashing on the desktop.

Comment: @Xen2050 I edited the question to include my grub.cfg and an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a *lot* of lines in that `grub.cfg`, I use a real basic one for my multiboot USB's, pretty much  a `set timeout` & `set default` & a few menuentry's...

I tried cutting away all the graphics-related stuff, and functions too, and was left with what might work as a no-frills `grub.cfg` to try out (keep the original as a backup, though it is pasted to that github website I'd do a `mv` on the original anyway):

```
set timeout=-1


if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option 

menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc' {



insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
fi
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-29-generic root=UUID=5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc ro quiet splash 
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-29-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc' {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-29-generic-advanced-5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc' {



insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
fi
echo 'Loading Linux 3.16.0-29-generic ...'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-29-generic root=UUID=5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc ro quiet splash 
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-29-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-29-generic-recovery-5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc' {


insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
fi
echo 'Loading Linux 3.16.0-29-generic ...'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-29-generic root=UUID=5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc ro recovery nomodeset
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-29-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-23-generic-advanced-5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc' {



insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
fi
echo 'Loading Linux 3.16.0-23-generic ...'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic root=UUID=5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc ro quiet splash 
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-23-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-23-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-23-generic-recovery-5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc' {


insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
fi
echo 'Loading Linux 3.16.0-23-generic ...'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic root=UUID=5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc ro recovery nomodeset
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-23-generic
}
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
fi
knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5165d33f-4b1c-41e9-9ca9-e1c831348abc
fi
linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
```

That might be able to at least get GRUB to display something...

Comment: Booting with `nodmodeset` by default *and* the modified file you gave me still doesn't work on the desktop. Still can't get to grub. Laptop apparently will boot anything at all because it's working fine.

Comment: Not sure, could try removing everything except a plain menuentry... but maybe barking up the wrong tree... the UEFI & things like legacy &/or secure boot still causing troubles. Not sure why the live usb would work though... maybe it's grub could be copied/modified  :-/

Comment: I went looking for its grub but couldn't find it. I'll try the menu entry thing.

Comment: IIRecall, the live iso's might've used syslinux or something a little different from regular GRUB actually :-\

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that I've answered my own question. After formatting the external drive and doing a clean install of 14.04 (as opposed to 14.10) I was still having the same problems. It would seem, after a great deal more reading on the subject, that either through my own sheer ignorance or mysterious dual UEFI Bios gremlins I managed to install a legacy-only version which will not boot in legacy mode with CMS... Twice. I'm now attempting an EFI-only install in the hopes that I won't have room for this same error. Either way, I think that closes this question. To future persons with this problem: the community page on UEFI is very useful.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_partition